# What is the best way to manage home page banners in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

This is my banners structure in home page :

[image: Banners Structure]

As you can see I have 4 section for banners - *small banners | medium banners | news banners | large banners*

And I have one model called `Banner` , 4 controllers to manage this banners and 4 tables to save data.

This is `Banner` model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'image', 'url', 'image_title', 'image_alt'
    ];
}
```

And Controllers :

**SmallController :**

```
class SmallController extends Controller
{
    public function small_list()
    {
        $smallBanners = DB::table('small_banner')->get();
        return view('admin.banners.small.list', compact('smallBanners'));
    }

    public function small_create()
    {
        return view('admin.banners.small.add');
    }

    public function small_store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'url' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'image_title' => 'max:255',
            'image_alt' => 'max:255'
        ]);
        DB::table('small_banner')->insert($data);
        return redirect(route('admin.banners.small.index'));
    }

    public function small_edit($id)
    {
        $small = DB::table('small_banner')->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('admin.banners.small.edit', compact('small'));
    }

    public function small_update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $small = DB::table('small_banner')->where('id', $id)->first();
        if ($request->has('image')) {
            if (file_exists($small->image)) {
                unlink($small->image);
            }
            DB::table('small_banner')->where('id', $id)->update([
                'image' => $request['image']
            ]);
        }
        DB::table('small_banner')->where('id', $id)->update([
            'title' => $request['title'],
            'url' => $request['url'],
            'image_title' => $request['image_title'],
            'image_alt' => $request['image_alt']
        ]);
        return redirect(route('admin.banners.small.index'));
    }

    public function small_delete($id)
    {
        $small = DB::table('small_banner')->where('id', $id)->first();
        DB::table('small_banner')->where('id', $id)->delete();
        if (file_exists($small->image)) {
        unlink($small->image);
        }
        return redirect(route('admin.banners.small.index'));
    }
}
```

Other Controllers are like **SmallController**

And this is how I show this banners :

```
@foreach($smallBanners as $small)
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
             <div class="widget-banner card">
                  <a href="{{ $small->url }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                     <img class="img-fluid w-100" loading="lazy"
                          src="{{ $small->image }}" title="{{ $small->title }}"
                          alt="{{ $small->image_alt }}" width="350" height="200">
                  </a>
              </div>
         </div>
@endforeach
```

Other views like small banner.

But in this case, for example in small banners, if we upload 5 images instead 4 images, the structure will be messed up.

What is the best way to manage this banners and optimize codes ?

Comment: if your banner template are optimized only for 4 banners, you can limit data list returned from server to random 4 banners from database

Comment: But I don't want to return 4 random banners, I need exactly 4 banners @AlzafanChristian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's back to the concept, starting from reducing table usage, or you can stay with your concept

lets's change the structure into below

table : `banners`

columns :

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('title');
$table->string('image');
$table->string('url');
$table->string('image_title')->nullable(); //guessing from validator that it can be null
$table->string('image_alt')->nullable();
//extra columns
$table->enums('banner_type', ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'news']);
//or
$table->string('banner_type');
$table->boolean('isActive')->default(0);
```

you have model, but not using it

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'banners'; //add this line to define table name, make sure you have set the database config in .env
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'image', 'url', 'image_title', 'image_alt', 'banner_type', 'isActive'
    ];
}
```

now reducing the controller used to manage banners into just 1 Controller

```
use Banner;

class BannerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $banners = Banner::get();
        return view('admin.banners.index', compact('banners'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.banners.create');
    }

    public function store_count($request, $type)
    {
        //using array limit
        return Banner::where('banner_type', $type)
        ->where('isActive', 1)->count() < $this->limits[$type] && $request->isActive == 1;
    }

    public function update_count($banner, $type)
    {
        return Banner::whereNotIn('id', [$banner->id])
        ->where('isActive', 1)
        ->where('type', $banner->banner_type)->count() < $this->limits[$type] && $banner->isActive == 1;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validating form data
        $data = $request->validate([
            'title' => "required",
            'url' => "required",
            'image' => "required",
            'image_title' => "max:255",
            'image_alt' => "max:255",
            'banner_type' => "required|in:small,medium,large,news",
            'isActive' => "nullable|in:0,1" //active or not
        ]);

        //validating images active count
        if (!$this->store_count($request, $request->banner_type)) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())
            ->withErrors(['isActive' => ' نمیتوان بیشتر از ' . $this->limits[$request['banner_type']] . ' عکس برای این بنر آپلود کرد! ']);
    }

        Banner::create($data);
        return redirect(route('admin.banners.index'));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $banner = Banner::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.banners.edit', compact('banner'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $banner = Banner::findOrFail($id);
        //validate update form data here
        //your validation
        //validating images active count
        if(!$this->update_count($banner, $request->banner_type)){
            return redirect()->back()
           ->withInput($request->all())
           ->withErrors(['isActive' => 'There cant be more than '.$this->limits[$request['banner_type']].' images active');
        }
        $banner = $banner->fill([
            'title' => $request['title'],
            'url' => $request['url'],
            'image_title' => $request['image_title'],
            'image_alt' => $request['image_alt'],
            'banner_type' => $request['banner_type'],
            'isActive' => $request['isActive'] ?? 0
        ]);
        if ($request->has('image')) {
            if (file_exists($banner->image)) {
                unlink($banner->image);
            }
            $banner->image = $request['image'];
        }
        $banner->update();
        return redirect(route('admin.banners.index'));
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $banner = Banner::findOrFail($id);
        if (file_exists($banner->image)) {
           unlink($banner->image);
        }
        $banner->delete();

        return redirect(route('admin.banners.index'));
    }
}
```

now we setup code to choose which images are active, you can use ajax method or use controller above

```
public function set_active($id)
{
     $banner = Banner::findOrFail($id);
     $this->validate_count((new Request([])), $banner->banner_type);
     $banner->update(['isActive' => 1]);
     return redirect(route('admin.banners.index'));
}

//you can use array if want to set different limit of banner type, put it as public variable inside controller class
public $limits = [
    'small' => 4,
    'medium' => 4,
    'large' => 4,
    'news' => 4
];
```

load the data resource into view

```
public class home()
{
    $small = Banner::where('banner_type', 'small')
    ->where('isActive', 1)->get();
    $medium = Banner::where('banner_type', 'medium')
    ->where('isActive', 1)->get();
    $large = Banner::where('banner_type', 'large')
    ->where('isActive', 1)->get();
    $news = Banner::where('banner_type', 'news')
    ->where('isActive', 1)->get();
   return view('home', compact('small', 'medium', 'large', 'news'));
}
```

Comment: i forgot to put extra `filable` i will update it, and happy coding @Waltun

Comment: I'm using array limits, but this section -> $limit = $this->limits[$type];
        if($total > $limit){
           return redirect()->back()
           ->withInput($request->all())
           ->withErrors(['isActive' => "There cant be more than {$limit} images active"]);
        } doesn't work

Comment: did you put `public $limits` on top of the controller?

Comment: Yes, and when I check $limit and $total, this is ok, and when I dd(...) in if($total > $limit) it's ok, but return redirect didn't work and banner will be add @AlzafanChristian

Comment: sorry i didnt know that my full code will be used, my answer updated, maybe you can check the result again :)

Comment: It's ok now, but in this section return Banner::where('banner_type', $type)
        ->where('isActive', 1)->count() > $this->limits[$type] && $request->isActive == 1; we have to put '<' instead of '>'  and when I try to edit banner this code will be run return redirect()->back()
           ->withInput($request->all())
           ->withErrors(['isActive' => 'There cant be more than '.$this->limits[$request['banner_type']].' images active'); @AlzafanChristian

Comment: And one more thing is that who when I'm insert new banner and set isActive to 0, still don't let me to add banner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232843/discussion-between-alzafan-christian-and-waltun).